# Textbox hides behind soft keyboard on android browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a popup that contains an input text box. So when the popup up (focusing the text box), the keyboard hides the popup. so the user unable to see what he enters. This issue presents in some android devices. But, in IOS,the text box is shifted to visible area while the text box is in focus but it is not happening in some android devices.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: I do not have code. The question is straight forward "The text boxes are  hidden behind soft keyboard in some devices(ex. HP tablet)". But in IOS, when the text box in focus it comes above soft keyboard. You can explain this by your own example.

Comment: It would definitely help to see code. E.g. only be the tags is it possible to deduce that you probably describe the behavior of a webpage or WebView here but this is just speculation.

Comment: See existing questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654865/keyboard-hides-input-fields-on-android-webview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194769/android-soft-keyboard-hides-inputs-from-cordovawebview-when-in-fullscreen